# Cannot compile tensorflowlite C++ API on android

Tags: android, tensorflow, cmake

I think the problem is I'm not including the shared library in the right away, but I'm not sure.

The error I get is

```
error: undefined reference to 'tflite::InterpreterBuilder::operator()(std::__ndk1::unique_ptr<tflite::Interpreter, std::__ndk1::default_delete<tflite::Interpreter> >*)
```

Which points at the last line of:

```
std::unique_ptr<tflite::FlatBufferModel> model = tflite::FlatBufferModel::BuildFromFile(casemodel_path.c_str());
tflite::ops::builtin::BuiltinOpResolver resolver;
tflite::InterpreterBuilder builder(*model.get(), resolver);
std::unique_ptr<tflite::Interpreter> interpreter;
builder(&interpreter);
```

I took this from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/examples/minimal/minimal.cc), as the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/apis) seems to be out of date.

I compiled tensorflow from source using NDK16b. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49834875/problems-with-using-tensorflow-lite-c-api-in-android-studio-project) to compile it.

The relevant portion of my cmake file looks like:

```
[...]
# Flatbuffer
set(FLATB_DIR <path-to>/git/flatbuffers)
include_directories(${FLATB_DIR}/include)
include_directories(${FLATB_DIR}/grpc)

file(GLOB flatb_src "${FLATB_DIR}/src/*.cpp")
add_library(flatbuffer ${flatb_src})

add_library(libtensorflowlite SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libtensorflowlite PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        <path-to>/app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libtensorflowlite.so)


include_directories(<path-to>/git/tensorflow-android)
[...]
target_link_libraries(flatbuffer libtensorflowlite <tons-of-other-libraries>)
```

As I mentioned already I think the problem is I'm not including the shared library in the right way. All I've done is created the folder(s) `jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/` under `src/main`, where I put the `libtensorflowlite.so`. Googling around that seems to be one way to do it? I've tried some other ways (with `sourceSets` and `implementation fileTree` but nothing worked).

I've got some other precompiled libraries that I'm using just fine, but they are static (in `target_link_libraries` I point directly to their path). Is it a problem mixing static/shared libraries like that?

edit: Following [this](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/compiling-a-tensorflow-lite-build-with-custom-operations-cf6330ee30e2), I also tried using ndk15c and editing `ANDROID_NDK_API_LEVEL`, but that did not help.