# How to use a TensorFlow Lite model in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, tensorflow-lite, ml-agent

I would like to write an Android game in Unity which makes use of an already existing pre-trained neural network which I only have as a .tflite file.

My first plan involved converting the .tflite file into a .nn file which then could be used by Unity's ml-agents. However, so far I have only found a way to convert frozen graphs (.pb) into .nn and I can't find a good way to get from .tflite to .pb . Other ideas to tackle the problem would also be very appreciated.

Comment: You can use the TFLite C++ APIs from Unity, can't you? Just follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50332808/192373).

Comment: Thank you. I did a bit more reading on it and it seems that you're right.